# ubuntu update to 18.04 error found when loading /etc/profile cannot set LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES, LC_ALL to default

Tags: locale, ubuntu-18.04

After updating from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 I receive the following warning: error found when loading /etc/profile cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale. The warning message also lists LC_MESSAGES and LC_ALL as having the same problem.

Here is my /etc/profile

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

when I tried ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales, it returns...

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTI-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
locales-all installed, skipping locales generation
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL="en_US.UTI-8" LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo locale-gen 
[sudo] password for go: 
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
go@go-Aspire-TC-705:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
locales-all installed, skipping locales generation
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTI-8"
```

I now can run a program that required locale, but the update-locale complains about invalid locale settings.

I'm over my head here. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the last Error message listed in my question, I noticed that LC_ALL was being set to LC_ALL="en_US.**UTI**-8". I edited the /etc/default/locale and changed the UTI to UTF and now everything appears to be working. I'm not 100% sure that the locale-gen command assigned LC_ALL to UTI... I don't believe I did that.

In any event my solution is sudo locale-gen, edit the /etc/default/locale to

```
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
#LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this along with multiple others, my locale was all jacked up, autocompletion was haywire, dpkg was throwing errors on installs. couldnt get anthing to change by unset or updating locale the problem was missing directory

```
/usr/lib/locale/locale.archive
```

made sure default locale file

```
/etc/default/locale
```

was correct then ran `sudo locale-gen` and it updated everything correctly

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: Sorry I’m new here